# Como excluir um selectbox com JavaScript um a um

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá...
Eu tenho um botão que ao clicar no botão "addpergunta" "clona" meu selectbox que está como "Selecione a Pergunta...". A cada clique ele adiciona mais um sempre incrementando id para que fique diferente.
Eu queria fazer o contrário, tipo... ao clicar no botão de id "cancelar" exclua os select's um por um.
Fiz o código abaixo mas ele só deixa hidden um select...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cancelar').click(function () {
        var 
        $('#3').html('');  // Excluindo pelo id
        $('#3').hide();
    });
});
```

**JavaScript e HTML que adiciona o selectbox**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = 1
    $('#addpergunta').click(function () {
        var itemCont = $("#itemCont").val();
        var novoItem = $("#1").clone();

        novoItem.attr("id", itemCont).attr("name", itemCont);

        $("#perguntas").append("<br />");
        $("#perguntas").append(novoItem);
        itemCont++;
        $("#itemCont").val(itemCont);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="itemCont" value="2" />
<div class="col-md-6" id="perguntas">
  <select class="form-control" name="1" id="1">
    <option value="0">Selecione a Pergunta...</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-9">
    <button type="submit" id="incluir" class="btn btn-default" style="height:35px; width:70px;">Incluir</button>
    <button type="button" id="addpergunta" class="btn btn-success" style="height:35px;" title="Adicionar Pergunta">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="cancelar" class="btn btn-danger" style="height:35px;" title="Cancelar">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi fazendo isso...

```js
var perguntaId = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addpergunta').click(function () { 
        var itemCont = $("#itemCont").val();
        var novoItem = $("#pergunta_1").clone();
        novoItem.attr("id", 'pergunta_' + itemCont);

        perguntaId = itemCont;

        $("#perguntas").append('<br />');
        $("#perguntas").append(novoItem);
        itemCont++;
        $("#itemCont").val(itemCont);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#remover').click(function () {
        console.log(perguntaId);
        if (perguntaId > 1) {
            $('br').last().remove();
            $('#pergunta_' + perguntaId).remove();
            perguntaId--;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você é capaz de obter uma lista com cada elemento `"select"` que você criou, use o método `$.fn.remove`. Isso irá remover cada elemento (da página) que você tem em um objeto instanciado da classe do jQuery.

```
$("#perguntas select").remove();
```

Isso faria o mesmo:

```
$("#perguntas select").each( 
/* novo estilo de função */
() =>
    /* statement único */
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
);
```

Explicação:

- iterata cada elemento de um objeto do jQuery;
- para cada elemento, uma remoção da página HTML.

Lembrando: você não irá perder referência aos seus elementos quando for removê-los, eles serão removidos apenas da página. Quando um elemento (que é um objeto) não é mais usado, o navegador remove ele automaticamente, isso acontece por causa do gerenciamento de memória ([garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/864516)).

Então, vamos supor que temos um código onde temos um elemento HTML armazenado em um objeto ou variável:

```
var el = document.getElementById("id");
```

Quando for removido da página,

```
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

`el` ainda será um elemento HTML (em navegadores modernos, todos elementos HTML seriam objetos, mas, em navegadores antigos como MS Internet Explorer 6 um elemento HTML seria mais nativo e não poderia obter manipulação de métodos, pois a interface `HTMLElement` não existiria).

**Edit**: Esqueci que você quer remover um por um elemento. Isso vai depender da ordem. Se você quer remover o elemento primário você pode usar o método `$.fn.first` que irá retornar o primeiro elemento do seu objeto do jQuery, e dessa maneira você não irá precisar saber se o elemento existe já que o jQuery executa uma ação para cada elemento que tem no bolso apenas se existe (loop), em seguida você poderá remover os elemento(s) contidos no novo objeto.

```
$("#perguntas select").first().remove();
```

Ou, se você quiser remover pela ordem de baixo:

```
$("#perguntas select").last().remove();
```

Comment: Boa explicação, mas o que eu quero é remover um "select" cada vez que clicar no botão.. e com esses códigos que passou remove tudo dentro da div.

Comment: @MarcosHenrique Então você precisa capturar o primeiro elemento "select" do objeto do jQuery, checar se ele existe e finalmente remover ele, ou usar o método `$.fn.first` para capturar o primeiro elemento. Isso removerá de primário em primário.

Comment: @MarcosHenrique Editei

Comment: Fiz diferente... criei uma variável e mandei excluir enquanto for maior que 1 (Meu select original)...  Mas agradeço a ajuda, deu uma clareada boa sua explicação.